# detect EOF of excel file in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have written a code for detecting the EOF of an excel file using python:

```
row_no = 1
while True:
    x = xlws.Cells(row_no,1).value
    if type(x) is None:
        break
    else:
        print(len(x))
        print(x)
    row_no = row_no + 1
```

i expect the while loop will stop then x becomes a "blank cell", which I support to be None, but it doesn't work, and it go to len(x) and prompt me an error of NoneType has no len. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here is your problem:

```
if type(x) is None:
```

If x is None, its *type* is NoneType. Therefore, this is never true, so you never see the blank cell and you end up trying to get the length of None.

Instead, write:

```
if x is None:
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using pywin32com ... **you don't need to loop around finding "EOF"** (you mean end of Sheet, not end of File).

If `xlws` refers to a Worksheet object, you can use this:

```
used = xlws.UsedRange
nrows = used.Row + used.Rows.Count - 1
```

to get the effective number of rows in the worksheet. `used.Row` is the 1-based row number of the first used row, and the meaning of `used.Rows.Count` should be rather obvious.

Alternative: use [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org) ... [dis]claimer: I'm the author.

Comment: I use xlrd and xlwt all the time :)

Comment: wah, this is better!
i wanna use xlrd also, but my xls file is password protected

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other comments you can use 'xlrd' as well to know the limits of the excel file as:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook (excel_loc)
excel_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

print("no of rows: %d" %excel_sheet.nrows)
print("no of cols: %d" %excel_sheet.ncols)
```